# Delayed jobs - uninitialized constant while using rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, nameerror

When I try to run Delayed::Job.all (for example, anything concerning delayd jobs won't work) in the rails console I get a "NameError: uninitialized constant Delayed" error. I have no idea why is that, especially since the gem itself seems to be working just fine.

By the way, I've run into this problem while trying to figure out how to clear a single queue in delayed jobs, still haven't gotten to make it work. Maybe anyone here knows how to do that?

EDIT: 
I really should check everything possible before posting, turns out I just needed to restart the console (looks like i haven't done it in ages). Still the second part of the question remains.

How can I clear a single queue in delayed jobs?

Comment: How is delayed job declared in your Gemfile

Comment: gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

Comment: And the gem declaration isn't in a group?  What versions of rails and delayed job are you using?